# Previously functioning backup drive on mac, suddenly is read only?

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod

I have a seagate 8TB External Harddrive, which has been used by the time MAchine on my macos for a while normally. also I have a folder on this harddrive where I have some videos ( tv shows, etc etc )
Yesterday I double clicked on the device and it showed as read only, Not read / write .[image: info of my harddrive]

I tried to add myself to the system as a user, but the plus button is greyed out, I go to terminal and go to /Volumes and do a

```
sudo chmod -R 777 Backup\ Disk
```

I get this message repeating on all files in the hard drive

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on Backup Disk/Backups.backupdb blah blah blah.Operation not permitted
```

I went to disk utility and tried to unmount and remount, still shows up as read only !!

Any ideas?
Keep in mind that this was functioning 24 hours ago, I have updated my macos to

```
   macos catalina 10.15.4 (19E287)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: in the "Time Machine" section of System Preferences, I removed the backup disk and added it back. Nothing lost and Time machine backing up files again.